# Probability involving 6 Letters.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a randomly selected permutation of the letters G, G, I, W, L, E would spell "wiggle"?

A. 1/720
B. 1/360
C. 1/180
D. 1/90

Answer (score 2):

You have 6 letters (let's call them G<sub>1</sub>, G<sub>2</sub>, I, W, L, and E so we can tell the G's apart). Thus, there are $6! = 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 720$ permutations of them.

Of those 720 permutations, precisely 2 of them spell the word "wiggle": WIG<sub>1</sub>G<sub>2</sub>LE and WIG<sub>2</sub>G<sub>1</sub>LE. Hence, your probability is $2/720 = \boxed{1/360}$.